# Correct Series/Parallel 12v SLA Wiring?

Tags: batteries, wiring, parallel, series

Is this an optimum wiring scheme for draining and charging seven 12v SLA batteries of different amp hour ratings wired in series/parallel for 72v 28ah output?
(powering a scooters speed controlled 1.5kw brushless motor)
[image: Wiring sketch...]

Comment: That's not too bad. Ideally you won't discharge them too deeply, deep discharge shortens SLA life significantly.

Comment: What might be a good lower limit discharge for run of the mill batteries with the indicated ratings? 30% overall?